# Applying the proof of "The subgroup of an infinite cyclic group is cyclic"

Tags: group-theory

First of all I want to say question is already asked under the title " A subgroup of cyclic group is cyclic- Understanding the proof" Sorry I dont have the link, but my question is entirely depend on that proof, 
My question is-
As there is not mentioned that the cyclic group is finite or infinite , i guess the theorem is for both finite and infinite group.
Now we know that the additive group of integers is infinite cyclic group generated by -1 & +1, thus Z is generated by a=-1 or +1 ( as in the proof generator of group is denoted by a) , then I have subgp of Z as 2Z , right? Then in the proof we have a^n belonging to H for some positive integer n. That means 1^n for some n should belong to 2Z!!!!! But that number comes to be 1 for any n which is not in 2Z! 
Please help me where Am I going Wrong?

Comment: Whats wrong in my question? Please tell me where I am going wrong in this question?

Comment: If you make it a torturous experience for someone to read your question, you will get downvotes. So, write shorter sentences. Use correct punctuation. Do not write five exclamation marks in a row. Do not use capital letters incorrectly. Use proper TeX formatting. And so on...

Comment: I accept. Sorry for the mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confused about notation. For $a \in G$ where $G$ is a group with operation $\star$, we write $a^n$ to mean

$$a^n = \underbrace{a \star \dots \star a}_{n\text{-times}}.$$

But the group $G$ in this situation is $\mathbb{Z}$ with the operation $\star = +$, the usual addition. Instead, then, $a^n$ is $\underbrace{a + \dots + a}_{n\text{-times}} = n \cdot a$ where $\cdot$ is the usual multiplication.

You'll notice that $H = 2\mathbb{Z} = \langle 2 \rangle$ and $2 = 2 \cdot 1$.

Comment: Yes, got the proof.

Comment: For the additive group, we take multiple of a i.e na not a^n